# Perl running two while loop subroutines in parallel

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am looking to run two subroutines in parallel, where both perform the same task on an android handset using ADB commands.  With help from SO and other research I have produced the following code below, however I am new to multithreading and I get an error of 'Free to wrong pool' during execution.  I am assuming I get this as I am using the $_ variable in both threads, is this correct?  I am using Windows7 to run this, but my Perl interpreter crashes on running this script.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;
use EFS_Handle;
use HelperFunctions;
use threads;

#### Various ADB command sequences follow ####
#### Start of multithread to run the same function on different android handsets ####

my @jobs;

push @jobs, threads->create(
    sub {
        print "\n\t" . curTime() . " :\t DUT Time at start of MPLMN search";

        open my $fh1, '>', "output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";
        my $pid1 = open my $log1, "-|", "adb -s 42d8d7dd logcat";

        system('adb -s 42d8d7dd shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER');

        while (<$log1>) {
            $fh1->print($_);
            last if m/Sorted scan results/;
        }
        kill "TERM", $pid1;
        close $log1;
        print "\n\t" . curTime() . " :\t DUT Time at End of MPLMN search\n";
    }
);

push @jobs, threads->create(
    sub {
        print "\n\t" . curTime() . " :\t REF Time at start of MPLMN search";

        open my $fh, '>', "output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";
        my $pid = open my $log, "-|", "adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF logcat";

        system('adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER');

        while (<$log>) {
            $fh->print($_);
            last if m/EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/;
        }
        kill "TERM", $pid;
        close $log;
        print "\n\t" . curTime() . " :\t REF Time at End of MPLMN search\n";

    }
);

$_->join for @jobs;
```

Comment: can you provide exact error with line number? side note; parametrize your function as they are 99% similar

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this.  The error I get is this >>>  Free to wrong pool 2a3fec0 not 5a8790  on line >>>  while(<$log1>) { <<<  In the first thread.

Comment: Try upgrading your version of Perl.

Comment: Hi ikegami, I'm using Strawberry Perl version 5.18.1, so I was hoping it would be reasonably up-to-date.

Comment: Why not use fork? the threading of perl isn't that good / stable. The error you are seeing is caused due to (a) shared object being mishandled. You aren't actually sharing data between the two threads, so just do a fork()

Comment: @nrathaus Notice that OP is on Windows, so forking and threading boil down to the same thing (if I understand the fork emulation on Windows correctly).

Comment: The code of forking even on Windows, works better than Threading in perl. At least from humble experience. If he  still wants to use threads, I at a lost at the moment why he gets that error

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback.  I will give a try with forking and get back to this (or setup a new question) if things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) module is famously not thread-safe

If you remove `use Win32::OLE` (you don't seem to use it) then your code will run fine

If have my doubts about **adb** cooperating with multiple simultaneous commands, but that is a different matter

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be related to the fact you are writing from both threads to the same file "output.txt" with ">". Try opening them with ">>".

Also remember to close that file.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a posted as a comment

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am assuming I get this as I am using the $_ variable in both threads..."*

If you use strict, and `$_` is in separate methods/subroutines, then there should be no global-access problems.